Pass array argument into C++ function from Python via SWIG
I've got an interface such as:
int func(int array[]);

I must call it from Python via SWIG. The binding code is already compiled and I do not want to edit, compile or otherwise mess with SWIG, but the overload for func(int[]) seems available -- SWIG prints it in the exception log.
How can I call this? It should be pretty standard, but neither func((1,2,3)) nor func([1,2,3]) works and there doesn't seem to be any obvious way to do it.

What happens if you use func([1,2,3])?

@mkrieger1 Something like: ERROR:client:Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'new_X'. Possible C/C++ prototypes are: X(int), X(int const []).
X(int) works.

What happens if you pass a python array (import array)?

Also, be sure to specify the type of the python array as integer (int). Python lists and tuples are heterogeneous, arrays are not.

@stateMachine Still exactly the same error. To make sure, this is the array: array('i', [0, 1, 2]). It seems SWIG is unable to handle this at all.

This is a non-answer since it does not really solve the problem of passing an array argument to a C++ function in a generic fashion via SWIG.
There was a:
%array_class(int, IntArray);

declaration inside the .i file for the SWIG wrapper I was handling. So I merely used a array = IntArray(size), filled the array and things worked out as intended.
There does not seem to be any other way to do this.
